# Black screen after presenting model view controller in current context from tab controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, popup, runtime-error

I'm creating a Popup error message for my own app. I have followed a tutorial in [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5i8n_bqblE). As my app is a tab bar app when Popup, comes up and a user presses another tab and then get back to that specific tab the background is changed !!!! any Idea what is happening here?

**1. This is when the popUp comes up**
[image]

**2.This one is when has change the tab and then came back to that specific tab**
[image]

**3.This is the last state when the user close the popup after they changed the tab**
[image]

none of these bugs happens if the user closes the pop up at the beginning!

```
let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ErrorVC")
self.present(next!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and this is the code I have used in my page to show the pop when it meets the conditions !!!

I have 2 `viewController` and second one is the pop up.

[image]

Comment: where are you dismissing your view controller ????

Comment: Where are you adding the popup as a subview? and are you dismissing it anywhere?

Comment: in the error vc I have declared a button: @IBAction func BtnOk(_ sender: Any)
 {
  dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `definesPresentationContext` property to `true` of `UIViewController` in first `viewController` where you're displaying `pop-view`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

Comment: It indicates whether this view controller's view is covered when the view controller or one of its descendants presents a view controller.

Comment: More info by apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621456-definespresentationcontext

Comment: is there any way I could blur the background? I mean the first vc when the popup comes up

Comment: Yes you can add subview and set background color and alpha of the view

Comment: I think if I set the alpha less than 1, it decreases the opacity of everything in that vc !!! Am i right?

Comment: this GitHub reference is so good, but I need to blur the background instead of that animation

Comment: how Should I disable the navigation bar/tab bar button when the popup is on the screen?